# Magento 2 extension attribute issue for Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface

Tags: magento2.2, extension-attributes

i am trying to add extension attribute for Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface but i am facing below issue.

```
Message: Property "Addressfiled" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtensionInterface".
```

Any one could you please provide solution for this.

Comment: Once you create an extension attribute  the corresponding setter class will be set in "/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Api/Data/AddressExtension.php" file.. Check If your extenstion att.is set in this file else try after clearing the generated files.

Comment: my attribute not appearing in that file.

Comment: Try clearing the generated files and check if the setter is autogenerated in interface and implementation classes.

Comment: Maybe you made a spelling mistake? Addressfiled -> **addressfield**

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute to your extension_attributes.xml file:

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
    <attribute code="attribute_code_here" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
```

After adding it you will have to run:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Hope it works